# HLA compilation error

Tags: assembly, x86, hla

Cannot understand what is wrong. Thanks for help

```
program first;

#include("stdlib.hhf");

static
    x: int16;
    y: int16;
    result1: int16;
    input: char;
    isEnd: char := 'n';

begin first;

    stdout.put("x = "); stdin.get(x);
    stdout.put("y = "); stdin.get(y);
    stdout.put("operation: "); stdin.get(input);

    while (isEnd == 'y') do

        if(input == '+') then
            mov(x, result1);
            mov(y, AX);
            add(AX, result1);
        elseif(input == '-') then
            mov(x, result1);
            mov(y, AX);
            sub(AX, result1);
        elseif(input == '*') then
            mov(x, result1);
            mov(y, AX);
            mul(AX, result1);
        elseif(input == '/') then

            if(y == 0) then
                stdout.put("y cannot be 0, setting result1 to 0", nl);
                mov(0, result1);
            endif;

            mov(x, AX);
            mov(y, result1);
            div(AX, result1);
        endif;

        stdout.put("result1 = ", result1, nl);

    endwhile;

end first;
```

I'm using hla 2.16 build 443 (prototype)
Error in file "first.hla" at line 31 [errid:129712/hlaparse.c]:
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('.

Comment: The parameters for `mul(AX, result1);` and `div(AX, result1);` are incorrect causing problems.

Comment: Possibly you meant `mul(result1, AX);` and `div(result1, DX:AX);`

Comment: For division you'd also have to make sure _DX_ is 0 before the division and The result will go into DX:AX not just AX. Div doesn't put a result into a memory address.